# Eclipse regular expression only modifies one line of file

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse and I want to comment out all lines in a feature file
I bring up the find/replace dialog
find: (.*$)
replace #$1

it correctly replaces the line where the cursor is at but no other line. I have also tried to select all lines but still only does one line. What do I need to do to replace all line with a # in front?

Comment: Use the 'Replace All' button

Comment: no did not work. Seems like the (.$) which I would think means match everything till the end of line for whatever reason would only get the one line. this however does do what I want but seems like overkill (^[\w|\W].$?)  .. which i would think means match word and non-word characters at the beginning of the line till the end of the line